# Is this very simple derivative correct?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I apologize for such a very easy question, but I'm really rusty. Is this very simple derivative correct?

> $$ \frac{{\rm d} }{{\rm d}x} 2^{(x+1)^2} = 2^{(x+1)^2}\ln(2)$$

Or would it be like this:

> $$ \frac{{\rm d} }{{\rm d}x} 2^{(x+1)^2} = 2(x+1) \cdot 2^{(x+1)^2} \cdot \ln(2)$$

I am using [this nice pdf](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/pdf/Common_Derivatives_Integrals.pdf) to remember the rules, but I am not sure about this case. Thank you!

Comment: It's the second one.

Comment: @vadim123 thank you! I was doubting about it. It has been a long time without touching derivatives.

Comment: $2^{(x+1)^2}=e^{ln2\cdot(x+1)^2}$; then apply chain rule: $(e^{f(x)})'=e^{f(x)}f'(x)$

Comment: @Alex Thank you! if you have time and you could add that explanation in an answer I would gladly accept it.

Comment: @iadvd In the future, if you just want to verify a derivative or integral or other calculation, you can use [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=d%2Fdx+2%5E((x%2B1)%5E2)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In calculus, I teach my students this substitution.

$2^{(x+1)^2}=e^{\ln 2\cdot(x+1)^2}$

Then remembering derivatives of things with $x$ in the power are quite simple: just apply chain rule, which states

$(e^{f(x)})'=e^{f(x)}f'(x)$

In this case:

($e^{\ln 2\cdot(x+1)^2})'=\ln 2\cdot 2(x+1)\cdot e^{\ln 2\cdot(x+1)^2}=\ln 2\cdot 2(x+1)\cdot 2^{(x+1)^2}$

The last step is just back-substituting the original function back into the result.

Note that this same rule also works when differentiating functions with $x$ both in the bottom and the power:

$(x^x)' = (e^{x\cdot \ln x})' = (1\cdot \ln x + x\cdot 1/x)e^{x\cdot \ln x} = (\ln x+1)x^x$

Comment: thank you very much for taking the time to answer! The reason for this question was asking this this new one: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1952774/it-is-possible-to-apply-a-derivative-to-both-sides-of-a-given-equation-and-maint

Comment: In my opinion, this is the absolutely best way to teach people how to do these types of derivatives..  Remembering the formulas for $log_a(x)$ and $a^x$ without $a=e$ is missing a good opportunity to show why $ln(x)$ rules and other tricks are useful.

Answer (score 1):

Another trick which is useful when you face products, quotients, powers, ... : it is logarithmic differentiation.

Let us consider your case $$y=2^{(x+1)^2}\implies \log(y)=(x+1)^2\,\log(2)$$ Differentiate both sides $$\frac{y'}y=2(x+1)\log(2)\implies y'=2(x+1)\log(2)\,2^{(x+1)^2}$$

Let do the same for $$y=f(x)^{g(x)}\implies\log(y)=g(x)\log(f(x))$$Differentiate both sides $$\frac{y'}y=\frac{g(x) f'(x)}{f(x)}+g'(x)\log (f(x)) $$ $$y'=f(x)^{g(x)-1} \big(g(x) f'(x)+f(x) \log (f(x)) g'(x)\big)$$